# Remove a specific filter in a Kendo Grid with toolbar template

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, telerik

I have a Telerik Kendo Grid with a toolbar template for create personalized filters.

I have 2 dropdownlist in my toolbar and the value selection must work in "And" with all filters (including the default filter of the grid).

When i want remove a filter i use this function:

**CODE**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 function removeFilter(filter, searchFor) {
    if (filter == null)
        return [];

    for (var x = 0; x < filter.length; x++) {

        if (filter[x].filters != null && filter[x].filters.length >= 0) {
            if (filter[x].filters.length == 0) {
                filter.splice(x, 1);
                return removeFilter(filter, searchFor);
            }
            filter[x].filters = removeFilter(filter[x].filters, searchFor);
        }
        else {
            if (filter[x].field == searchFor) {
                filter.splice(x, 1);
                return removeFilter(filter, searchFor);
            }
        }
    }

    return filter;
}
</script>
```

My problem is that my function removeFilter remove all the filters in my gridview when instead I would remove only the specific field.

I reproduce an [Example](http://jsfiddle.net/jebbo/gofo8sjr/2/) in jsfiddle.

**QUESTION**

What's the correct method for delete only a specific field from the filters of the grid?

**REFERENCES**

1. [GRID / Toolbar template](http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/grid/toolbar-template)

Comment: Why are you using recursion with `slice`?

Comment: I found that source here: http://www.telerik.com/forums/remove-filters-from-data-source#pJ9YFIbNWEqLbPKh55c6fQ
I suppose that splice() is used for remove the elements from array filters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your mistake is in `myFilterChange function`. You add filter on change but never remove the previous one. In the result of this you have condition like `idcat == 1 && idcat == 2` after second change of this combo box.

You should clean filter before add another for the same column [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gofo8sjr/5/):

```
if (statoFilterValue) {
    removeFilter(currFilters.filters, "idstate");
    currFilters.filters.push({ field: "idstate", operator: "eq", value: parseInt(statoFilterValue) });
} else {
    removeFilter(currFilters.filters, "idstate");
}
```

Also in `removeFilter function` you shouldn't use recursion in combination with splice. It is enough to asigne the result of `splice`

```
if (filter[x].filters.length == 0) {
   console.log('empty');
   filter = filter.splice(x, 1);
}
```

Comment: thank you suvroc. I clean filter before push the new filter and i remove the return recursive from function removeFilter and all work.

Answer (score 2):

remove filter  by name of the  filed

```
    function removefilter(filterField)
{
    //grid id
    var gridData = $("#your  grid  id").data("kendoGrid");

    // get currently applied filters from the Grid.
    var currFilterObj = gridData.dataSource.filter();

    // get current set of filters, which is supposed to be array.
    // if the oject we obtained above is null/undefined, set this to an empty array
    var currentFilters = currFilterObj ? currFilterObj.filters : [];

    // iterate over current filters array. if a filter for "filterField" is already
    // remove  filter  by  filed name
    if (currentFilters && currentFilters.length > 0) {
        for (var i = 0; i < currentFilters.length; i++) {
            //  for(var j=0; j<)
            if (currentFilters[i].field == filterField) {
                currentFilters.splice(i, 1);
                break;
            }
        }
    }



    gridData.dataSource.filter({
        logic: "and",
        filters: currentFilters
    });
}
```

add filter

```
    function applyFilter(filterField, filterValue) {

    // your  grid  id
    var gridData = $("#grid  id").data("kendoGrid");

    // get currently applied filters from the Grid.
    var currFilterObj = gridData.dataSource.filter();

    // get current set of filters, which is supposed to be array.
    // if the oject we obtained above is null/undefined, set this to an empty array
    var currentFilters = currFilterObj ? currFilterObj.filters : [];

    // iterate over current filters array. if a filter for "filterField" is already
    // defined, remove it from the array
    // once an entry is removed, we stop looking at the rest of the array.
    if (currentFilters && currentFilters.length > 0) {
        for (var i = 0; i < currentFilters.length; i++) {
            if (currentFilters[i].field == filterField) {
                currentFilters.splice(i, 1);
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    // if "filterValue" is "0", meaning "-- select --" option is selected, we don't 
    // do any further processing. That will be equivalent of removing the filter.
    // if a filterValue is selected, we add a new object to the currentFilters array.
    if (filterValue != "0") {
        currentFilters.push({
            field: filterField,
            operator: "eq",
            value: filterValue
        });
    }
    debugger;
    // finally, the currentFilters array is applied back to the Grid, using "and" logic.
    gridData.dataSource.filter({
        logic: "and",
        filters: currentFilters
    });

}
```

based  on this  [enter link description here](https://randombrainworks.com/2014/03/17/external-filters-for-kendo-grid/)